# Identifying two groups from an exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

I have the sequence $0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{s}\mathbb{Z}_k\xrightarrow{\times \ell}\mathbb{Z}_k\xrightarrow{t}B\rightarrow0$ where $\times\ell$ is multiplication by $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

Now, $ker(t)=im(\times\ell)=\ell\mathbb{Z}_k=\mathbb{Z}_{gcd(\ell,k)}$, so by the first isomorphism theorem we have that $B=im(t)\cong\mathbb{Z}_k/\mathbb{Z}_{gcd(\ell,k)}=\mathbb{Z}_{gcd(\ell,k)}$ since $gcd(\ell,k)\vert k$. So we have successfully determined $B$ in this sequence. But I'm unable so far to determine $A$. Would anyone be able to give me some suggestions on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: what does $\mathrm{im}(0 \to A) = \mathrm{ker}(s)$ tell you about $s$? Can you combine this with $\mathrm{im}(s) = \mathrm{ker}(\times \ell)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the sequence is *exact*.

The image of $0 \to A$ is then the kernel of $s$, which is $0$. Hence $s$ is injective and $A \cong \mathrm{im}(s) = \ker(\times \ell) = d\Bbb Z / k \Bbb Z$ for some $d \in \{0,...,k\}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand all this reasoning but I'm having trouble identifying $d$ - is there a simple way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: @FloydEverest : you can see that $d$ is the smallest positive integer such that $\ell d$ is an integer multiple of $k$. Does something like $d = k / \mathrm{gcd}(k, \ell)$ work?

Comment: I was just considering that myself - it does work since $\frac{k}{gcd(\ell,k)}\times\ell=\frac{\ell}{gcd(\ell)}\times k$ and $gcd(\ell,k)\vert \ell$ so this is an integer multiple of $k$! Thanks for the help

Comment: @FloydEverest : yes, and $d$ is as small as possible with this property :-).